# Django query across foreign keys

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to get a list of users who have been referenced as a `ForeignKey` in two other models. I'm still a little unclear on queries when they reach this complexity.

Models:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class EmailSent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In English, what I want to get is: 10 active users who have 0 pages and have never had an email with the name `check_in` sent to them.

Here's where I am:

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=1).annotate(page_count=Count('pages')).filter(page_count=0)[10]
```

but not sure how to do what is essentially:

```
email_sent = EmailSent.objects.filter(user=user, name='check_in')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to get what you want is:

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=1).annotate(page_count=Count('pages')).filter(page_count=0)
EmailSent.objects.filter(user__in=users, name='check_in')[10]
```

Another way is,

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=1).annotate(page_count=Count('pages')).filter(page_count=0)
users.emailsent_set.all()[10]
```

Comment: for the first one, that's two lines right?  Would the result of the second line be EmailSent objects or User objects?

Comment: Yes, both are 2 lines. The result of both is the EmailSent objects and not User.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=1)\
            .exclude(emailsent__name='check_in')\
            .extra(select={'page_count': "select count(*) from YOURAPP_page where user_id = auth_user.id"}, where=['page_count  0'])[:10]
```

Comment: User is a ForeignKey to EmailSent. Doesn't exclude(emailsent__name='check_in') only work if emailsent is actual IN the user model?

Comment: No, the code above should work, but I can't check it by myself. Check the [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)